# RxSwift using MVP subscribe from the Presenter

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have a searchBar to query results from an API. If i query directly from the VC without passing the text to the presenter i get this which works perfectly fine:

```
searchBar.rx.text
        .skip(1)
        .throttle(0.5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .flatMapLatest({ (text) -> Observable<[MarvelCharacter]> in
            return GetCharacters().execute(offset: 0, name: text)
        }).subscribe(onNext: { (characters) in
            self.showCharacters(characters: characters)
        }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

What i really want is to subscribe from GetCharacters() in the presenter.
Could be like this:

ViewController

```
    searchBar.rx.text
        .skip(1)
        .throttle(0.5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .map(presenter.searchTextDidChanged)
        .subscribe().addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Presenter

```
func searchTextDidChanged(text: String) {
    getCharacters.execute(offset: offset, name: text)
        .subscribe(onNext: { characters in
        (self.offset == 0) ?
            self.ui.showCharacters(characters: characters) : self.ui.appendCharacters(characters: characters)
    }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
```

But sometimes i send RxSw (show the result RxSwift) and RxSwZ (empty results), but since i lost the “chain”, getCharacters from the presenter gets executed twice. Then if the 2nd request terminates before the good request i end up in the searchBar with RxSw5 and in the results with RxSwift, how can i deal with this?

Comment: I'd like to help you, but it's hard to understand your problem without full code. Can you share for me a full code or part of the code with this problem using Github or Bitbucket?

Comment: I'm interested in your architecture. If you want to share an example of your core, I'll appreciate a lot. Best!